# Does this kind of pec fly reduce shoulder impingement?

Tags: tendinopathy, shoulder, rotator-cuff

http://www.nautilus.com/catalog/productdetail.jsp?PRODUCT%3C%3Eprd_id=845524441760486 claims that

> Internally rotated arm position reduces shoulder impingement

in this type of pec fly:

[image]

Is that true?

Videos of people using this pec fly:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joOwIJuL0NE
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shYrmYkHsD4

---

[Chest fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly_(exercise)#Chest_fly) (= pectoral fly = butterfly) machines are otherwise designed with one of the following two types:

[Type 1](http://bodybuildingplaza.blogspot.com/2012/07/pec-deck-machine-for-chest.html):

[image]

[image]

[Type 2](https://jet.com/product/detail/37093113329d4d658d16db64e6e7ef3b?jcmp=pla:ggl:gen_sporting_goods_a1:exercise_fitness_weight_lifting_a1_other:na:PLA_345660300_23686986540_pla-161706659820:na:na:na:2&code=PLA15&ds_c=gen_sporting_goods_a1&ds_cid=&ds_ag=exercise_fitness_weight_lifting_a1_other&product_id=37093113329d4d658d16db64e6e7ef3b&product_partition_id=161706659820&gclid=CjwKEAjw1qHABRDU9qaXs4rtiS0SJADNzJisFJec-sQkbBYIXspDN9MG0gQpHWlncloL-mxtLuNy4BoC0Vvw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't you think you'd be more likely to get good answers in Fitness?

Comment: @CareyGregory no